# Applescript waiting for close (I'd like it not to)

Tags: concurrency, applescript, launch

In Applescript, I have the following:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Vidalia.app/Contents/MacOS/Vidalia"
do shell script "/Applications/Firefox_3.6/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P Anon"
```

It works perfectly, but the issue is that it will wait for Vidalia to be CLOSED before it will then launch Firefox.  I would like to open both at the same time with one script.  I don't really understand the language and all of my searching has turned up nothing.  How can I get these open simultaneously?  That is the point, after all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're using 'do shell script' for this rather than just 'tell application blah to activate'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [open](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command to launch the applications:

```
do shell script "open /Applications/Vidalia.app"
do shell script "open /Applications/Firefox_3.6/Firefox.app --args -P Anon"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `do shell script`, AppleScript will wait for the response of the process you're running. As you're calling it, there's no option but to wait for the process to terminate, which is when the application closes.

To solve this, you need to replace your shell commands with ones that provide no response and terminate right away. So try this:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Vidalia.app/Contents/MacOS/Vidalia &> /dev/null & /Applications/Firefox_3.6/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P Anon &> /dev/null &"
```

I didn't test this with the applications you're using, as I have neither installed; instead, I tested with iTunes and Bento, with which it worked as you're hoping.

Comment: So both of your answers work to solve this question -- wish I could mark both.